# The area bound by the curve and its tangent.

Tags: calculus

[image]Suppose $C$ is the curve $y=f(x)$ with $f$ a twice-differentiable function such that $f''(x) > 0$ for each $x \in [0,a]$, where $a$ is a positive constant. Suppose $T$ is the tangent line to $C$ at a point $P=(r,f(r))$ on $C$ where $r \in (0,a)$. Let $A$ be the area of the plane region bounded by the $y$-axis, the vertical line $x=a$ the curve $C$, and the tangent line $T$. Show that $A$ is minimum if and only if $r=a/2$.

Comment: It's not homework, but it's a question from the study guide for my finals. I am really lost on this problem. It will be helpful if someone could give me a starting point.

Comment: Have you drawn a figure and tried to express $A$ in terms of $f, r$, and $a$?

Comment: Yes, I came up with int-f(x) - int-(f(x)+ f`(r)(x-r)). Is that even correct.

Comment: So what do you think.

Comment: Now I don't know how to prove that A is minimum when and only when r=a/2. Do I find the derivative of A and then use the extreme value theorem.

Comment: Why not try it and see what you find out?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
A(r) &= \int_0^af(x)dx-\int_0^a\left(f'(r)(x-r)+f(r)\right)dx  \\
&= \int_0^af(x)dx-\int_0^a\left(f'(r)x-rf'(r)+f(r)\right)dx  \\
&= F(a)-F(0)-\left[\frac {a^2}2f'(r)-arf'(r)+af(r)\right]  \\
&=F(a)-F(0)-\frac {a^2}2f'(r)+arf'(r)-af(r).
\end{align}

Then we differentiate to find the minimum of $A(r)$:

\begin{align}
A'(r) &= \frac {-a^2}2 f''(r)+af'(r)+arf''(r)-af'(r)  \\
&= \frac {-a^2}2 f''(r)+arf''(r)  \\
&= af''(r)\left(r-\frac a2\right).
\end{align}

Since both $a$ and $f''(r)$ are positive, we only care about $r-a/2$, which is zero at $r=a/2$ and switches from negative to positive at $r=a/2$ meaning that $A'(r)$ switches from negative to positive, meaning that $A(r)$ has a minimum at $r=a/2$. In this case, it is the absolute minimum, since there are no other critical points.